# Ionic Geocoder Address in different languages

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-geocoder

I have an ionic app. I can the goggle maps api in the index.html using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&amp;sensor=true&amp;language=en&amp;libraries=places"></script>
```

However my app has 2 languages which I translate using angular translate.

When the app is translated, the map and the geocoder doesn't change language. So I tried to add another

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&amp;sensor=true&amp;language=ch&amp;libraries=places"></script>
```

in index.html

But seems like it only takes one. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the Geocoder uses the browser's preferred language, or language specified when loading the API (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?csw=1#Localization).

I don't think you can load two times the API with two different languages specified. Instead you can try to load the API only when your local language is set (only one at a time).